# Skip a Cypress Test in Commandline

Tags: angular, azure-devops, cypress

I have a cypress integration test that I do not want to run in my CI/CD pipeline. I know I can use `.skip()` function to skip the test but what I am looking for is a way to exclude the test by passing some command line argument itself(like we have in case of Xunit test cases). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the tests you want to be run by using the `cypress run --spec` option. So you can move the tests you want to run into their own folder, `'cypress/integration/testsToRun/**/*'` for example, and Cypress will run only the specified tests and skip the rest.

Answer (score 4):

One option can be to use the Node package [cypress-select-tests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-select-tests). Once installed, you can add some keywords to your `describe()`.

eg. `describe('test name (ignore)', () => {`

And then run your tests based on the keyword `ignore`. Below command will run all tests except the ones which has ignore written in the `describe()`.

```
## runs tests NOT with "ignore" in the title 
$ npx cypress run --env grep='ignore',invert=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put an [Environment variable](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html) in cypres.env.json file and put the questionable It case in an if statement like:

```
context('conditional test', () => {
    if (Cypress.env('myVariable')) {
        it('conditional test', function () {
            //code to be run only if the variable is true
        })
    }
}
```